# Spring boot: Log file has get requests to static files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, spring-security

I have configured my app using

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {...}
```

Inside configure method, allowed the static content.

```
http .httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/*.js", "/resources/static/**", "/static/**", "/**/*.jpg", "/**/*.svg", "/**/*.ico", "/**/*.gif", "/**/*.css", "/register")
.permitAll()
```

application.properties :

```
logging.level.web=debug
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug
```

The problem i am having is that my log file is crowded by get requests to the static resources

[image]

I am just interested in logging access to controllers and not static files.

**Is there something i need to configure to exclude the logging of access to static resources?**

I have also tried

```
@Configuration
public class StaticConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/static/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("/static/");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue**

- You have enabled debug level logging for `org.springframework.web` package, so it will log everything

**Try this solution**

- Remove the debug level logging for `org.springframework.web`
- Create a subclass of CommonsRequestLoggingFilter

```
public class CustomRequestLoggingFilter extends CommonsRequestLoggingFilter {

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldLog(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return logger.isDebugEnabled() &&
               !request.getRequestURL().toString().contains("/static")
    }
}
```

- Create that filter as a bean

```
@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {
 
    @Bean
    public CustomRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CustomRequestLoggingFilter filter
          = new CustomRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(false);
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
        return filter;
    }
}
```

- Add the following to `application.properties`

```
   logging.level.<package of your filter>.CustomRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, log filter is a good idea. unfortunately i m still seeing the GET calls to static js, css files :(

Comment: static files are under resources/static/css  , resources/static/js etc.   Log has multiple lines like o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/proj/mybundle/css/icons/icomoon/styles.min.css", parameters={}  o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]

Comment: logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CustomRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG is the only logging related item and  the log is empty i.e. not even controller info

Comment: after removing org.springframework.web, i put a breakpoint in shouldLog and it hits them and now its blank output